# Trying to find a replacement door handle/knob

Tags: replacement, hardware, doorknob

I bought a house, and two of the closets are missing the door handle/knob.  It's a mortise lock (old house), and every other interior door in the house has the same handle, so I'd like to not get one of those glass ones that seem widely available and instead get a matching replacement for consistency throughout the house.

I've browsed dozens of pages on amazon, Schlage, Baldwin, etc.

This is the hardware kit.  The only part missing is the handle:
[image: Mortise Door Hardware Set]

Here is a door with the missing handle:
[image: Door with missing handle]

Comment: I disagree.  First, the situation is clearly described, and the problem is as specific as is possible.  Second, although the first response does recommend a specific product, my original hope was actually that someone knew of a general website, search, or method that could be used to track down this sort of information.  It could be applied not just to door hardware (my specific case), but any/all antique hardware & fixtures.

Answer (score 2):

Looks close enough to me (buy two, do both sides). Also, consider swapping a new one with the inner knob from one of the closets or any other less conspicuous door. If you don't like this one, search Google (not suppliers) with these key words:

Beaded Oval Door Knob: ([rejuvenation.com](http://www.rejuvenation.com/catalog/products/beaded-oval-knob/items/doorknob-beaded-oval-c4542-ob))

[image]